# how to create an array with custom data type?

Tags: c#, winforms, class

How can I make an array with 400 elements of type `myClass` and pass different args to each of them?
What type of array should I define and *where* should I do this?

Comment: This question needs tons of clarification.  I suggest you [edit] and provide details.

Comment: You don't pass arguments to arrays. I think you will have to revise what an array is.

Answer (score 2):

Basics of [arrays in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx):

```
MyType[] arrayOfMyType = new MyType[400];
```

`arrayOfMyType` will hold an array of 400 "slots" for `MyType`. You will need to iterate over it and assign an object to *each* "slot", as the values will default to the default of your type (`null` for reference types).